# Проблема с override метода Photon Unity Networking

Tags: unity3d, framework

Не работают 2-а override.

```
public override void OnPlayerLeftRoom(Player otherPlayer)
{
    Debug.LogFormat("Player {0} left room", otherPlayer.NickName);
}
public override void OnPlayerEnteredRoom(Player newPlayer)
{
    Debug.LogFormat("Player {0} entered room", newPlayer.NickName);
}
```

Весь код:

```
using Photon.Pun;
using Photon.Realtime;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks
{
    public void Leave()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.LeaveRoom();
    }
    public override void OnLeftRoom()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(0);
    }
    public override void OnPlayerEnteredRoom(Player newPlayer)
    {
        Debug.LogFormat("Player {0} entered room", newPlayer.NickName);
    }
    public override void OnPlayerLeftRoom(Player otherPlayer)
    {
        Debug.LogFormat("Player {0} left room", otherPlayer.NickName);
    }

}
```

Comment: может при вызове что-то не так?

Comment: Извините меня! Оно должно срабатывать когда к мастер клиенту подключается еще один игрок, а не когда создается комната. Спасибо!